# How to add context to the tomcat 8 configuration for java web application

Tags: war, tomcat8

I have deployed a Java Web application wbs.war in tomcat 8 and the application name is wbs. now when i enter http://localhost:8080 tomcat home page is coming but my requirement is user should see my application home page when he enters http://localhost:8080. is there way to append /wbs/ to the tomcat url so the url looks like http://localhost:8080/wbs/ by default?

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your war as `wbs.war` and configure the context root in `conf/server.xml` to use your war file:

```
<Context path="" docBase="wbs.war" debug="0" reloadable="true"></Context>
```

Please remove default `ROOT.war` and ROOT folder from webapps(folder)